# 'settings.DATABASES improperly configured. Please Supply the ENGINE value' - when adding legacy database

Tags: django, django-models

I've added a second databases and i've connected it to apps via routers... all works well, i can access the data via the admin panel for the respective models and fields as specificied in my models.py in the apps.. perfect.

One issue is when i run `python manage.py migrate`, I get an error saying  `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the  ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.`

## Database code in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { },
    
    'auth_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'network_db':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'Network.sqlite3',
    },
    'simulation_db':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'Simulation.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

## manage.py diffsettings command

```
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'NAME': '', 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'MIGRATE': True, 'MIRROR': None, 'NAME': None}}, 'auth_db': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': WindowsPath('C:/Users/backend/db.sqlite3')}, 'network_db': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': WindowsPath('C:/Users/backend/Network.sqlite3')}, 'simulation_db': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': WindowsPath('C:/Users/backend/Simulation.sqlite3')}}
```

I've followed the documentation exactly which is how i've connected the legacy database and i'm able to access the data via admin panel.. however i am not sure what i'm doing wrong to cause the error when running `python manage.py migrate`

EDIT:
I got it to work!! I changed my DATABASE in settings so that the default was the authdb like so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'network_db':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'Network.sqlite3',
    },
    'simulation_db':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'Simulation.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `default` database hs no `'ENGINE'`...

Comment: that worked thanks!! Also I have another issue where i'm trying to inspect a db with the following command but it's giving me "The connection 'Network' doesn't exist" with this command ```python manage.py inspectdb --database=network > output.py```

Comment: It is `network_db`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem brooo it worked ffs I was trying every name other than the name i specified in the settings.py file.. i thought it was the name of the file, i.e network.sqlite3 LOL.. . many thanks!!!